# I want to go inside a folder and run a command in windows command promt using a single command

Tags: windows, cmd

C:\node_modules>cd npm (Hit Enter)

C:\node_modules\npm>node connect.js (Hit Enter)

executing connect.js...

The above 2 commands, I want to execute from a single command from the folder location "node_modules". For Example,

C:\node_modules>cd npm/node connect.js

But it doesn't work. whats the right command?

Comment: `npm\node connect.js`?

Comment: `cd npm & node connect.js`

Answer (score 0):

With the current directory already as `node_modules`, you could use:

```cmd
Start "" /D npm "%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\node.exe" connect.js
```

or

```cmd
Start "" /D npm /Wait "%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\node.exe" connect.js
```

or

```cmd
PushD npm 2> NUL && "%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\node.exe" connect.js & PopD
```

or

```cmd
CD npm 2> NUL && "%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\node.exe" connect.js & CD ..
```

---

With any directory as current, you could use:

```cmd
Start "" /D "%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\node_modules\npm" "%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\node.exe" connect.js
```

or

```cmd
Start "" /D "%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\node_modules\npm" /Wait "%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\node.exe" connect.js
```

or

```cmd
PushD "%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\node_modules\npm" 2> NUL && "%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\node.exe" connect.js & PopD
```

---

You could shorten those seven examples by omitting the full paths and extensions, if you can guarantee that their locations are set within the environment and the `%PATHEXT%` variable contains `.EXE`

```cmd
Start /D npm node connect.js
```

```cmd
Start /D npm /W node connect.js
```

```cmd
PushD npm 2>NUL&&node connect.js&PopD
```

```cmd
CD npm 2>NUL&&node connect.js&CD..
```

```cmd
Start "" /D "%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\node_modules\npm" node connect.js
```

```cmd
Start "" /D "%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\node_modules\npm" /W node connect.js
```

```cmd
PushD "%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\node_modules\npm" 2>NUL&&node connect.js&PopD
```

---

I have assumed for the above examples, that the file `node.exe`, and directory `node_modules`, are both really located in `"%ProgramFiles%\nodejs"`, usually *(`"C:\Program Files\nodejs`)*. If one or both of those locations differ on your PC, please modify them accordingly.